# Jquery replace with regex: replacing an attribute in SRC with another attribute

Tags: jquery, replace, find, src

I'm using Google Static Maps, which loads an image map:

```
<img src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/....&someparameter&someparameter&scale=1">
```

Notice the `"scale=1"` parameter at the end. I need to replace it with `"scale=2"` only on high density displays with WebKit to load a high resolution version from Google.

I'm using this find/replace script on DOM load with a condition, and it doesn't work. The window.devicePixelRatio works in WebKit (tested); but something is probably wrong with the function inside the if condition.

```
$(function()
    {
        if (window.devicePixelRatio >= 1.5)
        {
            $('img[src*="scale=1"]').each(function() {
                var newSrc = $(this).attr('src');
                newStr = newSrc.replace('/scale=1/','scale=2');
                $(this).attr('src', newSrc);
            });
        }
        else
        {
        }   
    });
```

Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: Any Javascript errors in your browser?

Comment: no, because .replace() is just having a hard time find the word '/scale=1/' in that string. Either lose the slashes and make it a string, or drop the quotes and make it a RegExp literal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're getting the `src` attribute value, storing it into a variable called `newSrc`, then replacing the `scale=1` and storing the result in `newStr`, then you're setting the `src` attribute of the image to `newSrc`, the original value?

Shouldn't it be:

```
$('img[src*="scale=1"]').each(function() {
    var newSrc = $(this).attr('src');
    newSrc = newSrc.replace('scale=1','scale=2');
    $(this).attr('src', newSrc);
});
```

Comment: More likely it should be `newSrc = newSrc.replace(...);`, then setting the attribute value using `newSrc` - otherwise you end up with a completely unnecessary extra variable (which is globally scoped to boot).

Answer (score 4):

[.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) takes either a RegExp or a string, you gave it a string that looks like a RegExp:

```
newStr = newSrc.replace('scale=1','scale=2');
```